# error :document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, mongodb-query, pymongo

Tried to store twitter stream data into MongoDB. The code is pretty much a copy from http://stats.seandolinar.com/collecting-twitter-data-storing-tweets-in-mongodb/  but always show an error. If I tried to print out the data, it shown json file continuously grow, but it seems never ends in spite of the time limit for the while loop.!

```
class listener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, start_time, time_limit=60):     
        self.time = start_time
        self.limit = time_limit

    def on_data(self, data):     
        while (time.time() - self.time) < self.limit:    
            try:
                tweet = json.loads(data)
                client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
                db = client['twitter_db']
                collection = db['twitter_collection']
                collection.insert_many(tweet)
                return True
            except BaseException, e:
                print 'failed ondata,', str(e)
                time.sleep(5)
                pass
                exit()

    def on_error(self, status):
        print statuses
```

Comment: What is the output of `type(tweet)`?

Answer (score 8):

You are using the wrong method to insert the document into your collection. In your case, [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) returns a dictionary not a `list` thus you need to use the [`insert_one`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one) method to insert that single document because [`insert_many`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) only insert an iterable of documents.

Comment: I changed it. it did not show the same error but seems still to take forever to run in spite of the time limit for while loop.